# PHP: Convert string to each integer variable

Tags: php, string, integer

I have a comma-separated string with a few integers, for example:

```
12 , 13 , 9
```

How can I convert the string above into 3 integer variables in PHP? Example:

```
$a=12 
$b=13 
$c=9
```

Comment: `$x = array_map('trim', explode(',', $string)); list ($a, $b, $c) = $x;`?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Stackoverflow is not a code-service website. Kindly post what have you done and we'll be glad to help you out.

Comment: Problem Solved. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using,

```
<?php
 $your_str = "12 , 13 , 9";
 $array = explode(',', $your_str);

 echo $array[0]; //12
 echo $array[1]; //13 and so on...

?>
```

**explode** works quite similar to split() which has been deprecated.
Hope it helps!